# Looping thru node children, wrapping with <li /> & cleaning up HTML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, replace, children

What is the best way to 'clean up' the HTML in this node?

I want to:

- Wrap the `<p>` tag in a `<div>` (done)
- Wrap each node following the first `<input>` - `<label>` set with `<li>` tags
- 'Clean up' the HTML: delete the `<br>` and `&ndash;`

I need to be able to handle either of these two examples of the HTML:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="firsttodo" class="function-check" id="id_firsttodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_firsttodo">First To-Do</label>
    <br>
    &ndash; 2-List item 1<br>
    &ndash; 2-List Item 2<br>
    &ndash; 2 List Item 3
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="ndtodo" class="function-check" id="id_ndtodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_ndtodo">2nd To-Do</label>
    <br>
    &ndash; <input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="sttodo" class="function-check" id="id_sttodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_sttodo">2)1st To-Do</label>
    <br>
    &ndash; <input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="ndtodo" class="function-check" id="id_ndtodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_ndtodo">2)2nd To-Do</label>
</p>
```

What I want:

```
<div class="ToDo"> 
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="firsttodo" class="function-check" id="id_firsttodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_firsttodo">First To-Do</label>
    <li>2-List item 1</li>
    <li>2-List Item 2</li>
    <li>2 List Item 3</li>
</p>
</div>
<div class="ToDo">
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="ndtodo" class="function-check" id="id_ndtodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_ndtodo">2nd To-Do</label>
    <li><input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="sttodo" class="function-check" id="id_sttodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_sttodo">2)1st To-Do</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" protocol="/" rel="TestNote" name="ndtodo" class="function-check" id="id_ndtodo">
    &nbsp;<label for="id_ndtodo">2)2nd To-Do</label></li>
</p> 
</div>
```

My script so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').each(function() {
        var L1 = $(this).children();
        for (var i = 2, len = L1.length; i < len; i++) { //skipping #s 0 & 1, want to keep them as is!
            var x = L1[i].nextSibling;
            if (x) {
                $(x).wrapAll('<li />');
            }
        }
        $(this).wrapAll('<div class="ToDo" />');
    })
});
</script>
```

I'm fairly sure `removeChild()` will remove the node AND it's siblings. So I'm seriously brain dead.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there no way to change the HTML output at the first place?

Comment: @Terry No. I'm working with a wiki and trying to set up a 'To-Do' system, eventually with draggable DIVs. Anyway, the HTML is set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're almost there.

http://jsfiddle.net/RpXBT/

Add

```
$(this).find('br').remove();
```

to the end. What's left? I'm also removing instances of `&nbsp;`. It's much better to use CSS for your formatting.

```
label {margin-left: 6px;}

$(this).replace('&nbsp;', '');
```

Oh, and your LIs are invalid unless they're wrapped in a UL.

This is as close as I got. I'm out of time for the day. Best of luck. http://jsfiddle.net/RpXBT/2/